# SQL Server data display for month start and end of a year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like this in SQL Server:

```
 MONTH_START | MONTH_END
-------------|-----------
 01-2014     | 01-2014
 02-2014     | 02-2014
 03-2014     | 03-2014
 05-2014     | 05-2014
 08-2014     | 08-2014
 10-2014     | 10-2014
 11-2014     | 11-2014
 12-2014     | 12-2014
```

How do I aggregate the dates to get something like this :

```
 MONTH_START | MONTH_END
-------------|-----------
 01-2014     | 05-2014
 08-2014     | 08-2014
 10-2014     | 12-2014
```

The final display should be: if all 12 months of a year exist in data, let's say the year is 2014, then the MONTH_START is 01-2014 and MONTH_END is 12-2014. If some month does not exist, then it should display as above table.

Comment: please add more detail about data structure

Comment: @davejal I don't think you really need more data. The idea is that OP wants to aggregate his months to get timespans instead of individual months.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Will `MONTH_END` always be equal to `MONTH_START`?

Answer (score 1):

In your result table, Is it

```
<tr>
    <td>09-2014</td>
    <td>12-2014</td>
</tr>
```

or

```
<tr>
    <td>10-2014</td>
    <td>12-2014</td>
</tr>
```

You can try the query below to get the result:

```
SELECT  
    MONTH_START,
    MONTH_END = (
        SELECT TOP 1
            MONTH_START
        FROM
            MonthStartEnd
        WHERE
            DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CAST(REPLACE(MONTH_START, '-', '-01-') AS DATETIME)) NOT IN (
                SELECT
                    CAST(REPLACE(MONTH_START, '-', '-01-') AS DATETIME)
                FROM 
                    MonthStartEnd ) 
         AND CAST(REPLACE(MONTH_START, '-', '-01-') AS DATETIME) >= CAST(REPLACE(se.MONTH_START, '-', '-01-') AS DATETIME))
FROM 
    MonthStartEnd se
WHERE
    DATEADD(MONTH, -1, CAST(REPLACE(MONTH_START, '-', '-01-') AS DATETIME)) NOT IN (
        SELECT
            CAST(REPLACE(MONTH_START, '-', '-01-') AS DATETIME)
        FROM 
            MonthStartEnd )
```

Comment: it should be <tr>
    <td>10-2014</td>
    <td>12-2014</td>
</tr>

Comment: Edited post to include the script to get the result.